# What to pass to reqwest::multipart::Part::reader

Tags: rust

I'm trying to upload a file (the name is dynamicly retrieved from the command line args) usind the `reqwest` crate.
I need to use the multipart form to upload the file. And since I want to upload large files in chunks I'm guessing that I need to use either `reqwest::multipart::Part::reader` or `reqwest::multipart::Part::bytes`. But both of the expect values with a `'static` lifetime.
How do I get my file into into the fitting format to use these methods and get the expected lifetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Careful with the lifetimes. `request::multipart::Part::reader`'s `'static` lifetime isn't on the **argument borrow** but on the **type**. The requirement is that the type definition will still exist for the lifetime of the function, which is a really easy requirement to fulfill. No part in the usage of `reqwest::multipart` actually borrows anything from the outside without making a copy of it internally.

In practice, any instance of `Read` will satisfy reqwest's multipart `reader` method, allowing you to pass arbitrary readers, even those you generate yourself.

In your specific case, you'll be uploading a large file. I'm going to deliberately pretend you are passing a reader (as you're specifically requesting to see how to use this method) as opposed to just using `Part::file`, which does exactly what I'm about to show you under the hood.

First, we're going to be opening our file:

```
let reader = std::fs::File::open("test.txt")?;
```

Nothing surprising there, it's worth noticing that `File` implements `Read`.

We then create our `Part`:

```
let part = reqwest::multipart::Part::reader(reader).file_name("foobar");
```

I've set the file name along the way. From here, we create our `Form`, because that's what we'll be sending. Note that the `Part` we created earlier is moved into this struct:

```
let form = reqwest::multipart::Form::new();
let form = form.part("test", part);
```

And then we send the request:

```
let client = reqwest::Client::new();
let resp = client
    .post("http://localhost/foobar")
    .multipart(form)
    .send().map_err(|e| io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::InvalidData, "Invalid server return"))?;
```

And, sure enough, it worked!

[image]

The file contained `foobar` (6 bytes, as seen on the screenshot).